scale the x y and z dimensions individually in asymptote
Is there a scaling operation which can transform this box into a cube, a la https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731044/319072?
The goal is to individually scale each axis.
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
    unitsize(1cm);
    import three;
    draw(box((-1,-2,-3), (4,5,6)));
\end{asy}
\end{document}


